# extract hidden email from webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract the email from this webpage:
https://aiwa.ae/company/arad-building-material-trading
I tryed requests and Beautifulsoup and they didn't worked.
I created this code using selenium but didn't worked as well:

```
from selenium import webdriver

u = "https://aiwa.ae/company/arad-building-material-trading"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(u)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[5]/a').get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: do you get error or what? Maybe you should use `class` or `id` in `xpath` instead of all these `div`

Comment: how about `xpath('//li[@itemprop="email"]/a')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to print email:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://aiwa.ae/company/arad-building-material-trading")
driver.maximize_window()
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@itemprop='email']/a"))).text
print(email)
```